# What are these 0.1'' header 'pin protectors' called?

Tags: connector, header

I was browsing Hackaday a few weeks ago and came by these 0.1 header "pin protectors". I have tried googling every term I could imagine and searched all related categories in Digikey and Mouser, but I had no luck finding any information on them.

What are these called? Where can source them from?

[image: Text]
<sub>(source: [jeff.glass](https://jeff.glass/wp-content/uploads/2020/03/IMG_9967-scaled-e1583254082764.jpg))</sub>

Comment: They're probably just pieces of insulation from some suitably-sized random wire.

Comment: Like slide-on pin labels they appear to be custom made. I have worked in several MFG plants and this is the first time I have seen them.

Comment: what do they look like from the side?

Comment: Why would anyone want them? As Dave says they look like the scrap insulation that falls from automated wire cutting and stripping and crimping machines.

Comment: Sometimes this is done to protect the pins from conformal coating sprays. They are re-usable up to a certain point.

Answer (score 2):

Heat shrink. 2:1 Polyolefin 3/64" diameter (that's the un-shrunk diameter) by the looks of it, or a similar metric size.